# Access and modify data offline on mobile when data isn't in cache

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, offline

I have a client who has users that work offline A LOT on mobile.

The Salesforce1 app has huge limitations in the number of records you can access (i.e. ones in your cache that you have looked at recently), which isn't good enough for the client. They need to be able to create and edit large sub sets of data, which they may not have looked at recently.

Similarly if you create an Account offline on mobile, you cannot create a contact associated to that account until you reconnect and sync.

I know there are apps such as Pulsar which do this, but the client wants something more bespoke.

How easy would it be to develop an app to enable users to create sequential child records offline on mobile? And to be able to access a large subset of data they may not have looked at recently?

Or is there another solution I'm not even aware of?!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds familiar! Our solution [MobileCaddy](http://www.mobilecaddy.net/) is a design/build/support integrated solution for fully offline, fully custom mobile apps built specifically for the Salesforce.com platform (and available from the [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q79ZEAQ))

[Here is a link](https://youtu.be/S7effj589ms) to an architectural overview that will give you some context.

The solution allows you to define a data structure on platform as well as define data restrictions, record conflicts etc. The whole product covers design/build/test/deploy/manage/monitor/versioning.

For your two requirements it is totally feasible to create offline child records and associate to offline created parents (3 levels supports with config only). And in terms of data you can define this and volumes at the platform side to suit your exact needs (rather than have users have to choose)

If this sounds like something you'd like to know more of you can contact me directly  (justin@mobielcaddy.net)

Even if you'd just like to know more about the approach and architecture happy to have a chat through :)